# Screen update bug in Experience section of Careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Editing one of the roles in the Experience section of my profile results in a small rendering error. If I have this title/company, you can see those items are bar-separated:

> Software Engineer | Start-up

If I edit them, even leaving them unchanged, it swaps to a comma using a JavaScript DOM update:

> Software Engineer, Start-up

Refreshing the screen entirely goes back to a bar, which I think is the intention. I'm on Firefox/Ubuntu 14.04. I run NoScript, so whilst I don't think the issue is on my side, it is possible.

Comment: Looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be resolved now. We were using an old view to update these sections and they're using the new ones now.

Comment: Seems fine to me, thanks!